# Centering Content In IE9+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I realize this question has been asked a bunch of times, but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. Basically my  tag will not center in IE9+. Its using margin: 0 auto.
I have added text-align:center to the body and html styles. I have a valid doctype. The only thing is I have some PHP that is before the doctype. If that is the problem how do I get around that?

Here is my code:

CSS

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: GothamBook;
    text-align: center;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-image: url(../Images/bg-pattern-gray.png);
}

main{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

>
index.php

```
<?php

    include_once "../PHP/HeaderFooter.php";
    include_once "../PHP/Event.php";

    $headerFooter = new HeaderFooter();
    $eventID = "";

    if(isset($_GET['eventID']) && !empty($_GET['eventID'])){
        $eventID = $_GET['eventID'];
        $event = new Event($eventID);
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
            echo "<title>" . $event->eventTitle . "</title>";
        ?>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/reset.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/global.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/event.css' />

    </head>
    <body>
        <main>content</main><script src='../JS/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../JS/jquery.expander.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../JS/expanderScript.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies. Didn't even think to see if the main tag was supported. I decided to just change the main tag to a div with the id of main. Its an easy fix that way.

Comment: what's the `<main>` tag?

Comment: `main` isn't supported by IE. And if I remember correctly, non-supported tags are not styled. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main for the compatibility. You can use modernizr to fix this, since it uses `document.createElement('main')` which then, IE start styling it.

Comment: You can also implement html5shiv into your site. That would fix it as well. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer does NOT support `<main>`. None of them. See [CanIUse (at notes)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main).

And because of that, IE does NOT style elements it does not support. You can use [html5shiv/html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) which is the polyfill or [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that has the polyfill and much more.

From now on, IE will style it. But then you need to set main's default CSS, which specifically is missing on your CSS, as @bboysupaman noted:

```
main { display: block; }
```

Or just use a [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which covers all default styles for everything before any other css you use.

#### Proof:

Just an update proving my point to user [C-link Nepal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138752/c-link-nepal) and his [magic IE](https://www.nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/shia-labeouf-magic-gif.gif) that renders `main`:

I tested on a real IE10, not emulated stuff. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9rq8e6r/2/).

Open the iframe url on the IE: http://fiddle.jshell.net/h9rq8e6r/2/show/ If was REALLY block, the below wouldn't happen!

[image]
(Paint skills ftw)

Comment: You proved me wrong as using sometext<main></main>sometext, good call. Thanks and +1.

Comment: But in case of OP there's no such text outside the main tag and should be working fine without adding block...

Comment: Inline elements do not accept `margin` so his attempt to `margin:0 auto;` will not center.

Comment: If you don't use any text outside the main tag it would work like block element please test it once yourself as I've shown in my fiddle...

Comment: Using OP CSS alone would make it align center on IE if this is what you would like show me (see http://jsfiddle.net/h9rq8e6r/7/show/ on IE10, its centered on same line.). But the point is that for IE, that element isn't a block. And what you failed to see is that if you look at OP's CSS, he is trying to use `main` as we would with `<div id="main">`, that is - `width: 940px; margin: 0 auto;` having a fixed width and centered. The example he posted would work by itself if was only one line he wanted on the entire page.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your css:

```
main {
display: block;
}
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: @C-linkNepal IE does not understand main tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main for the compatibility

Comment: @C-linkNepal In your haste to down vote me, you've seem to have forgotten that IE9 does NOT support the Main tag  (nor does IE10 or IE11) and you have to set the display to block. While IE9+ supports the HTML5 section elements, it does not support HTML5 grouping elements.

Comment: If you are using the html5shiv, then it does. But you have to tell it to.

Comment: @C-linkNepal Sorry dude but you ARE wrong, and you are downvoting wrongly. Please research more before spitting nonsense :-)

Comment: @RaphaelDDL please try this in ie then tell me how's that work <main>asdf</main><p>asdf</p> the text is block level element...

Comment: @C-linkNepal if you are using modernizr/html5shiv and reset.css, it will work.

Comment: @C-linkNepal Clearly you have something installed on your server or in your browser that is allowing you to see main as a block level element. Try using your web inspector to identify what is causing it. But regardless, no version of IE supports the main element.

Comment: Please copy the code from jsfiddle and save it like test.html and check it in ie9+ You'll see that working because main and footer tags are displaying as block element...http://jsfiddle.net/h9rq8e6r/

Comment: Let it go man. It is common knowledge that IE does not support the main element.

Comment: Please try it once. I'm curious that when I checked it, it's recognizing, please make me wrong if it's wrong. Just check it once...

Comment: Okay. I am trying it now.

Comment: I double checked. Still doesn't do it. It is possible for it to appear that way if you center the body element. Then the inline main element fills up the body element and has the appearance of being centered itself.

Comment: @C-linkNepal Updated my answer with a screenshot of a real IE10, not an emulated one using your fiddler (improved since you don't need doctype, html and body tags, fiddler already adds them).